# Filtering Test Cases by Tester

Tags: filter, azure-devops, manual-testing

My organization is new to using Azure DevOps, and as the project manager of a major software upgrade, I have been tasked with using DevOps to conduct our UAT. We have added test cases/Plans through a lot of trial and error, and are now completely lost on how to filter test cases by Tester. I have spent the better part of my day reading everything available online - and though we know that the email generation will give the tester a link to get to the test cases they have to run, our team leads need to be able to filter by a specific tester to see which test cases they have already been given.
Example:
TestSuite123 and TestSuite456 are assigned to me to manage. I've assigned John Doe and Jane Smith as testers to the 45 test cases within the suite. Now I want to make sure that I haven't given John more than Jane, so I need to see which cases I've specifically put John as the tester for - can I filter that?
I've looked in Queries, work items, etc. and "Tester" is not a field I can filter on in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use test suite **filter** directly on test suite **Execute** page to view how many test cases have to assign to each tester.  See below screen:

Go the test suite Execute page-->Click the **filter** icon on the top right corner-->Click the **Tester** to select the tester to filter. You can see the total test cases have been assign the tester.

[image]

You can also create a **Test result Chart** to track the number of the test cases that have been assigned to each tester. See below steps

1, Click the **Chart** Tab-->Click New-->Choose **New test result chart**
[image]

2,In the chart configuration page, choose **Group by Tester**. Then you will see the number of test cases for each tester on the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to create a test case chart:

Test case owners are tracked by the Assigned to field. Use a stacked bar chart or a pivot table chart. Choose Assigned to for rows and status for the columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops